# why is it that info.php only work if placed in /var/www/html not /var/www/?

Tags: php, apache

I have just deployed LAMP in preparation for Elgg installation. After I deployed apache and php I wanted to test my progress by creating info.php file. I placed the file in /var/www/ and tried to visit it from the browser only to get an error:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /info.php was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at 192.168.0.9 Port 80
```

when I placed the same exact file in /var/www/html it worked and displayed the Apache and php installation settings. Can anyone please explain to me why? for educational purposes.

Comment: because by default `/var/www/html` is the default document root.  You must change in httpd.conf if you want to just use /var/www/

Comment: Your configuration folder has the location where the root is, `DocumentRoot `. On my server that is in `httpd.conf` in `/etc/httpd/conf/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache webserver will show documents that are put to a specific location. Root of that location is referred as document root.

For example, if DocumentRoot were set to `/var/www/html` then a request for `http://www.yoursite.com/folder1/yourpage.php` would result in the file `/var/www/html/folder1/yourpage.php` being served to the requesting client

In ubuntu default location is `/var/www` for server root and on Centos its `/var/www/html`

This change requires a service restart.

you can change this from `/etc/httpd.conf` where there is a section about document root.

But again on your distro which is ubuntu its under `/etc/apache2/http.conf`

Debian based systems

```
ServerRoot              ::      /etc/apache2
DocumentRoot            ::      /var/www
Apache Config Files     ::      /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
                        ::      /etc/apache2/ports.conf
Default VHost Config    ::      /etc/apache2/sites-available/default,/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default
Module Locations        ::      /etc/apache2/mods-available, /etc/apache2/mods-enabled
ErrorLog                ::      /var/log/apache2/error.log
AccessLog               ::      /var/log/apache2/access.log
cgi-bin                 ::      /usr/lib/cgi-bin
binaries (apachectl)    ::      /usr/sbin
start/stop              ::      /etc/init.d/apache2 (start|stop|restart|reload|force-reload|start-htcacheclean|stop-htcacheclean)
```

Comment: I can't find http.config in this location?

Comment: Actually this file does not exist in Ubuntu http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DistrosDefaultLayout#Debian.2C_Ubuntu_.28Apache_httpd_2.x.29:

Comment: That is a reference link for you to go look. I am putting it to answer as well

Comment: I found it, to modify document root directory I needed to make changes in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

Answer (score 1):

Because `/var/www/html` is the default document root path of your apache.
You can edit the path  in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default.conf` You may. Find the DocumentRoot as

```
/var/www/html
```

[image]

Comment: I can't find http.config in either locations?

Answer (score 0):

Default DocumentRoot of apache is /var/www/html. Edit your httpd.conf config file located in `/etc/apache2` directory and change DocumentRoot to /var/www